# Arrays in J programming Language

Tags: c++, j

How does one do array accesses in the J programming language? For example, using C++ as my pseudocode language:

```
int M [100];  // declare an array called M
int j = 5;  //index into the array
int y = 10;  //value to store or load from the array

M[j] = y;  // store y into the array

y = M[j];  // load y from the array
```

What would these sorts of array accesses look like in idiomatic J?

Comment: [RosettaCode](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Arrays#J) might be a better forum for this type of comparison.

Answer (score 7):

The literal (but still pretty idiomatic) way to write this in J would be as follows.

```
m =: 100 $ 0   NB. This means create a 1d array consisting of 100 zeros.
j =: 5
y =: 10
```

With that initialization out of the way, now we're ready for the meat of the answer, which consists of two different usages of [the `}` adverb ("Item Amend" and "Amend")](http://www.jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d530n.htm).

```
m =: y j } m
```

Putting two arguments to the left of the `}` causes J to replace the `j`th element of the right hand argument `m` with the value `y`. NOTE: we had to assign the result back in to `m` because the result of `y j } m` was simply to compute a new array which incorporated the change that you requested using the `}` verb.

```
y =: j } m
```

Putting only one argument to the left of the `}` causes J to excerpt the `j`th element of `m` and return it. In this case, we set y to the result.

Comment: Note that the amend above will be executed "in place". J recognizes that the new array is being assigned to the same name and only writes the changes to the new array. See the http://jsoftware.com/jwiki/Essays/In-Place%20Operations . In my experience the  dyadic verb From http://jsoftware.com/help/dictionary/d520.htm `{`is more often used to retrieve items from an array.

Comment: Very good point, @Tikkanz. And thanks for the corrections in your edit.

Comment: OMG! I had no idea amend `}` had the single left argument feature! I just use the regular take `{`...

Comment: @MPelletier, @Tikkanz's correction that `}` is technically an adverb helped me internalize an important clarification here. Namely, in my examples above, the actual verb ends up being `(j })`, which when applied dyadically results in an amended array and when applied monadically does the same thing as Take.

Comment: The appearance of the phrase "two arguments to the left" telegraphs that misunderstanding. J syntax never involves two arguments to a single side. When arguments apply to a dyadic verb, or conjunction, it's an infix form with one argument on each side. In this case j is an argument to the adverb and y an argument to the resulting verb.